# Laravel showing index.php

Tags: php, laravel

Server Details:
windows server 2012 R2
Apache server 2.4
As IIS server works 8080 and Apache  works on 8181 port
PHP 7.4
Mysql Database

We need to deploy the Laravel project on 8181 port.

We have run the composer successfully. After that save the Laravel project on htdocs of Apache24 folder. In htdocs we created Laravel folder into that we keep all the Laravel project file. so the path is c:/Apache24/htdocs/Laravel/public/index.php

In url it also shows the path like http://ip address:8181/Laravel/public/index.php. It shows the landing page of website. After that when click on register page it shows the register controller name after index.php like below

http://ip address:8181/Laravel/Laravel/public/index.php/register

This shows the extension of file as well as public folder, which is not standard Laravel pratice

Comment: (1) Ensure your website root directory set to be `public` (2) Ensure `mod_rewrite` is enabled

Comment: That's a bit of a mess. If you own a DNS entry I suggest you map it to that IP and then you configure a virtual host on apache2 with a root directory in your project's public directory. That will allow you to access the site via `http://my.dns.example.com/` if this is impossible however you might need to copy the `.htaccess` from your public directory to the base directory and update the paths within it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use artisan command in terminal or cmd for running laravel project.

```
php artisan serve
```

when use this artisan command, laravel runs on port 8000 as default but if you want run project on custom port, you can use port flag in artisan commad

```
php artisan serve --port=8181
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some configuration

In your public directory all files cut and copy at your `Laravel` folder. And you have to change some configuration in your **index.php** file

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And just url like this

```
http://ip address/Laravel/
```

Comment: @GISKeeda I see your link. I think it works fine. But my question what do you want??

Comment: @GISKeeda May be it's better if you search `http://103.224.247.79` then your project shows. This is very simple way. Just few steps for you

Comment: That's exactly what we want that our IP Address to load the laravel application, we are trying that but it's not working, can you please help us with those few steps which u mentioned. (Eg: Do u mean redirection using httacess file or something)

Comment: which OS are you using?? Linux distributor??

Comment: We are using: - windows server 2012 R2   ,- Apache server 2.4 As IIS server works 8080 and Apache works on 8181 port   ,- PHP 7.4  - Mysql Database

Comment: May be I will help you if you are using linux distributor. My project is running what you want

Comment: Sure, I have also set up on Linux on Amazon AWS.